# using ehcache to handle file processing

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I am new to `ehcache` concept and its usage. in my application i am loading many files using `java.io` ( lets say 100 at a time. it may be more than that) and process these files using multiple threads.

from performance perspective i want to implement a caching mechanism for this. can anyone please let me know how should i do this and what will be the best practice ?

PS - processing file steps 
1. read the file
2. create java file object.
3. process the file.
4. move the file to a different location.

( i am using spring in my application)

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: @AaronSheffey - i am not clear what i would cache in what point. i think i need to cache the file objects once i read the file and process it through the cached object. i wonder weather it is the correct way. please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're operating a high traffic portal about 95M PIs / monthly. 
We're using proxy servers and varnish https://www.varnish-cache.org/ to cache static contents. 
At the same time you outsource caching from your application servers, and they've more free memory to operate on. I think it would be a right solution in your case , too.

Comment: thanks for your comment.can you please explain it more? i mean at what point i should add the objects to the cache? once i get the file objects should i add these to the cache and process it through the cached objects?

Comment: no, with varnish you're out of java scope and application server respectively. you cache the contents as static files on varnish in memory (or on disc) like CSS, HTML (which produced by your java application), XML, so on.